# Creation of secondary table from existing one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have an existing table name 'VALUABLE':

**FieldA**
10
14
30
18
16
19

I would like to construct another table 'NEWVAL' as follows:

**Field1  Field2 Field3**
10    ***** 14 ******   4
14  *****  30  ******  16
30  *****  18   ****** 0  (Instead of -12)
18  *****  16  ******  0  (Instead of -2)
16  *****  19   ****** 3

Field 3 is the difference of Field2 - Field1.  Any negative value obtained is given the value zero.

I need SQL help to do this.

Thnks in advance.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: Gordon the need is to display the second table exactly as I have posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have a column `id` in the table that specifies the ordering.  Basically, you want to implement the `lead()` function in SQL Server 2008 (it is in versions 2012+).  Here is a nifty way using `outer apply`:

```
select v.FieldA, vnext.VfieldA,
       (case when vnext.VfieldA >= v.FieldA then vnext.VfieldA - v.FieldA
             else 0
        end) as diff
from valuable v outer apply
     (select top 1 v2.*
      from valuable v2
      where v2.id > v.id
      order by v2.id desc
     ) vnext;
```

You might want a `where vnext.fieldA is null` to remove the last row.

Comment: Is the `Outer` keyword optional for an `Outer Apply`?  Not sure if it's a typo or if it isn't needed.

Comment: Thnks Gordon :) but where is the Outer Apply?

Comment: @Siyual . . . Actually, a `cross apply` is probably sufficient for your purposes, so it should work either way.